# Vuejs Router Async Component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, eslint, async-components

I am running a vue app with npm run serve.
I am injecting the components to the routes asynchronously and in my opinion is happening something strange as when I am not even at that path it shows me an error about a component of another path, saying that the file is missing... and it is true it is missing... but isn't that suppose to be injected when I am at that path? Looks like the component is already imported...

```
 const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [ 
       { path: '/login', component: () => import('./pages/login.vue') },
       { path: '/register', component: () => import('./pages/register.vue') },
    ]
```

I see this error in the compiler

```
./src/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './pages/register.vue' in '/home/daniel/work/someapp/frontend/src'
```

and the path is /login, of course all works properly when I create the register page... just don't understand why it gets imported when the route is not loaded yet.

Comment: use import('./components/pages/register.vue') and give a try

Comment: it gets imported correctly if I create the file... just why it imports it / checks for it when I am not at that route at all... this is my question

Answer (score 0):

You are right.

You won't get the error until you navigate to that route that has the erroneous import path.

However, you have specified `/login` for both login and register.

So if the register component import path is not correct you will get the error.

Here is a trivial implementation which demonstrates the same.

When you navigate to categories, you will see an error. But home, news and lists will work correctly.

[image: Edit Lazy loading routes with VueRouter]

Comment: Ops... that was a typo... corrected my question. I tried your example and it does as expected throw the exception when you navigate to the route with the missing component... while is not in mine... it occurs also with only these two routes

Comment: @daniel Can you share a codesandbox that replicates your problem?

Comment: Bah... still don't understand... https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-frost-ozm3o?file=/src/App.vue ... and this is all I have... but in the codesandbox works as expected...

Comment: @daniel Hard to tell then.
But if you are not able to replicate the error on sandbox, then most likely routing is not the issue. 
Worth checking your webpack config.
Also check the versions of vue and vue router.

Comment: I suppose this is related more to eslint... and it is not that important as long it imports asynchronously...